# How to paste special in Excel using Applescript?

Tags: excel, applescript

I am using Applescript to create a macro where data is transferred from several files to a single file. Data is copied with

```
copy range the_range destination clipboard
```

and pasted with

```
paste worksheet active sheet destination range "A1"
```

The problem is that most of the formatting is lost and I have not managed to get the "paste special"-syntax correct. I have downloaded "Excel2004AppleScriptRef.pdf".

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
paste special on worksheet active sheet destination range "A1"
```